# I got a error while trying to forward table values into a combo box

Tags: c#, sql, excel, exception

I am trying to past an Ms.Excel table column names into a combo box. i use the function bellow to do the activity but i get an exception look like this

> 'Metadata$' is not a valid name. Make sure that it does not include invalid characters or punctuation and that it is not too long.

Here is the code
     'Metadata$' is not a valid name. Make sure that it does not include invalid characters or punctuation and that it is not too long

```
  private void connection(String path)
    {
        string connectionString = string.Format(Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture, "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties='Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;'",path);
        DbProviderFactory factory = DbProviderFactories.GetFactory("System.Data.OleDb");
        using (DbConnection connection = factory.CreateConnection())
        {
            connection.ConnectionString = connectionString;
            using (DbCommand command = connection.CreateCommand())
            {
                command.CommandText = @"SELECT [File], [ItemName], [ItemDescription], [Photographer name], [Date], [Environment site] FROM [Metadata$]";
                connection.Open();
                using (DbDataReader dr = command.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    if (dr.HasRows)

                    {
                        while (dr.Read())
                        {
                            cmb.Items.Add(dr[0].ToString());
                        }
                    }
                }
                connection.Close();
            }
        }
    }
```

Note - i use openfiledialog to get the path of excel file

i used fallowing sql command instead of using one on the code.

```
"SELECT column_name from information_schema.columns where table_name = 'BigData' Order by ordinal_position";
```

which gives me below exception.

> "The Microsoft Access database engine could not find the object 'columns'. Make sure the object exists and that you spell its name and the path name correctly. If 'columns' is not a local object, check your network connection or contact the server administrator."

i would like to correct this errors. both or at least single one.

thank you.